# How to access default MongoDB database of Heroku. I uploaded on Heroku without any mongo string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I deployed a nodejs, MongoDB application on Heroku, without MongoDB string on Heroku. Now I want to access that MongoDB database. But I'm not getting any proper solution. Please help me.

I used `` mongoConnectionString: `mongodb://localhost:27017/DB ``.

while deploying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to hide your MongoDB string from your codebase, then you can just use env and upload the MongoDB string to your Heroku app's config, which you will find under your settings.

Comment: while deploying I just used   mongoConnectionString: `mongodb://localhost:27017/DB`. How can I access

Comment: you see this MongoDB instance is running in your local computer, so when you deploy your app it can not access the database as it is running locally on your computer, so you have to add a string of a deployed database. I suggest you check out MongoDB atlas